# Проверка орфографии в базах данных в текстовых полях

Tags: c#, firebird, sql-server, powershell

Доброго времени суток.

Есть много всяческих баз данных в форматах fireberd и mssql. Сотрудники зачастую допускают опечатки или орфографические ошибки.

Задача проверить текстовые поля на ошибки. Думаю вполне это можно сделать при помощи пакета msoffice. Выбрать данные не проблема. Вся задача сводится к проверке орфографии в переменной аля string

Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь.

Ps: сеть закрытая, доступ в интернет отсутствует, всякие сайты с апи отпадают.

Answer (score 1):

Выборкой получаем строку, кормим ее офису, делаем автоисправление , результат пишем на место.

Отдельным словарем проверять мороки больше, так как падежи, числа, роды.

Comment: Так собственно это и хочу сделать. Результатом операции хочется видеть перечень слов которые не нашлись в словаре. Грамматика не сильно беспокоит, но как бонус будет полезной.

С чего начать, чтобы проверить строку на орфографию?

Comment: Мне не нужно исправить все якобы ошибки в тесте, мне нужно найти слова сомнительного написания.

Comment: Начни с гугления о использовании офиса и С шарп, поймешь как строиться обьект вордовский , копнешь глубже поймешь как пользоваться словарем.

Код не приведу, так как не шарпист, но на делфях подобную задачу с правописанием писал, не скажу что просто но и не очень сложно.
Гласное понять обьектную модель офиса